How to model the constraints of min and max in cvxpy
I have a continuous variable $x_{ij}\in[0,1]$ and I need to write the following constraint:
$$M_i-m_i+1\leq C_i$$ where $M_i=\max\{j: x_{ij}>0\}$ and $m_i=\min\{j: x_{ij}>0\}$

How are $M_i$ and $m_i$ defined if $x_{ij}=0$ for all $j$?

That should not happen. For each $i$, we must have at least one $j$ such that $x_{ij}>0$.

Let constants $j_\min$ and $j_\max$ be the smallest and largest possible $j$ indices, respectively.
Introduce binary decision variable $y_{ij}$ to indicate whether $x_{ij}>0$.  Assuming $x_{ij}>0$ for at least one $j$, you can linearize as follows:
\begin{align}
x_{ij} &\le y_{ij} \tag1\label1\\
M_i &\ge j y_{ij} + j_\min(1-y_{ij}) \tag2\label2\\
m_i &\le j y_{ij} + j_\max(1-y_{ij}) \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $x_{ij}>0 \implies y_{ij}=1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces $y_{ij}=1 \implies M_i \ge j$.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces $y_{ij}=1 \implies m_i \le j$.

Thank you. But how this guarantees that $M_i-m_i+1\leq C_i$, for some given constant $C_i$?

You would also impose that constraint directly.
